# Gets the balance Of the specified address

Tags: solidity, remix, testnets, balances

Retrying the question, OBTAINED ANSWER DOES NOT RESOLVE THE PROBLEM.
I sent some eth to crowdsale contract but balance Of does not change. (to call the function I'm using Remix Ropsten test net).

The code is here: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc3ec072c279043ad2e56f4b5683b78337ed614d9#code

The suggestion of one of the members was to change,

[image]

I think the problem lies somewhere else, here;

function () payable public {  }

```
function buy () payable public  whenNotPaused beforeDeadline afterStartTime saleNotClosed {
    require(msg.value >= minContribution);

    // Update the sender's balance of wei contributed and the amount raised
    uint amount = msg.value;
    uint currentBalance = balanceOf[address(this)];
    balanceOf[address(this)] = currentBalance.add(amount);
    amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

    // Compute the number of tokens to be rewarded to the sender
    // Note: it's important for this calculation that both wei
    // and PDT have the same number of decimal places (18)
    uint numTokens = amount.mul(rate);

    // Transfer the tokens from the crowdsale supply to the sender
    if (tokenReward.transferFrom(tokenReward.owner(), msg.sender, numTokens)) {
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
        // Check if the funding goal or cap have been reached
        // TODO check impact on gas cost
        checkFundingGoal();
        checkFundingCap();
    }
    else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

I tried to change so and nothing, like this;

uint currentBalance = balanceOf[address(this)];

balanceOf[address(this)] = currentBalance.add(amount);

and ;
[image]

Is there anyone here who will tell me directly without guessing where the problem lies?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? You have two contracts a Token and a TokenSale both have a balance one in tokens and the other in ether.

Comment: Hi. the question is why a balance Of and the amount raised does not is updated( I'm call this function in Remix) after some ether was sent to the crowdsale contract?Thanks for the aswer.

Comment: That is because you ar calling the fallback function, and that function does nothing. You have to call the `buy` function.

Comment: I thought its gonna be updated automatically.Buy function(Remix)- give me this- "Gas estimation failed" and then
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x30e8f4c7e7de3d2e5d8160a5538e04fe4a6358d96a6cfe1626ebf33220bf903e
Why is  there any error in the code?

Comment: That is because you send 0 ether but in your code you have `require(msg.value >= minContribution);` and it will fail there.

Comment: The same problem-https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x72d97577e0690c44b5447590f26de8cdf9954d0fee78df621c373f5b41c388e7. Yes, but someone sends eth from the wallet to contract. Is not it like this?.Here eth was send https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc3EC072C279043AD2e56f4B5683B78337eD614D9

Comment: I see you use `token.transferFrom()` in your `buy()` function to transfer token from the `token.owner()`, but that requires the owner himself to call `token.approve()` beforehand. The common approach in token sales is at the start to assign directly the tokens to the TokenSale contract so you can call `token.transfer()` directly. At the end of the sale the contract will return unsold tokens to the owner of the contract.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I sent the tokens to the token reward address (210 000 000 PDT) and then I'd 
 call token.approve() beforehand. The crowdsale contract got (210 000 000 PDT).(allowance). 
I'd  assign directly the tokens to the TokenSale contract ;
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x79B67dFF9FB21d2550937d879Ec2eACB2F377DA0#tokentxns

Ethers were sent to Token Sale contract but the amount raised has not been changed. Why?
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xc3ec072c279043ad2e56f4b5683b78337ed614d9#readContract

Comment: You should try to use ganache and remix to test your contract it is very painful to debug things when running on testnet. You are using `https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x79b67dff9fb21d2550937d879ec2eacb2f377da0` as the `tokenReward` but that is not a token contract.